# Displaying bit(1) data

Tags: qgis, pgadmin

I'm having an issue showing a type *bit(1)* data in QGIS.

[image]

I can see the field in the DB Manager but once  I load the layer in QGIS, the field disappears.

Does it have anything to do with the default constraint :

[image]

Comment: not all Postgres types are supported in QGIS. You can create updatable views to serve/convert the data. Noe that it may be much simpler to just use the `boolean` type instead of a bit string of size 1.

Comment: This data is provided by an external source so we can only take it as it is but indeed, we decided to convert it to a boolean type in our internal database.